# How would I get a php uploader to upload to a specific username's directory?

Tags: php

I may be doing something horribly wrong, so that's why I want to ask this question.

```
{
    $pic = channelart.png;
    $pic_loc = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
    mkdir($userRow['user'], 0777, true);
    $folder="/.$userRow['user']";
    if(move_uploaded_file($pic_loc,$folder.$pic))
    {
        ?><script>alert('Successfully updated channel art.');</script><?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?><script>alert('Failed to update channel banner.');</script><?php
    }
}
```

I got this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/video10p/public_html/labs/au/index.php on line 7

Comment: You added you're code but forgot to add the error. Please add the error and read How to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

Create folder before upload image :-

```
mkdir($userRow['user'], 0777, true);
```

Your code like this :-

```
{
    $pic = 'channelart.png';
    $pic_loc = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
    mkdir(trim($userRow['user']), 0777, true);
    $folder="/.trim($userRow['user'])";
    if(move_uploaded_file($pic_loc,$folder.$pic))
    {
        ?><script>alert('Successfully updated channel art.');</script><?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?><script>alert('Failed to update channel banner.');</script><?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It still didn't work.
It returned the error:
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/video10p/public_html/labs/au/index.php on line 7"

Comment: $pic = "channelart.png"; change this line

Answer (score 0):

Change this `$pic = channelart.png;` to this `$pic = "channelart.png";`

You are getting the error because PHP is expecting a String, Variable or statement. The [`T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE`](http://php.net/tokens) token picked up on this line tells us that the parser came upon another assignment, when it was expecting a String, Variable or Numeric.

PHP Tokens are extremely useful to debugging and I would strongly advise taking a look at the page linked above.

This should solve your posted error above.